# Get the application icons for currently running tasks in android

Tags: java, android, task

I successfully got the application icons of the currently installed applications with the following snippet:

```
List<ApplicationInfo> list = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);

    for (int i=0; i< list.size(); i++)
    {
        randInt1 = new Random().nextInt(list.size());

        ApplicationInfo appInfo = list.get(randInt1);
        packageName = appInfo.packageName;
        appLabel = (String) pm.getApplicationLabel(appInfo);
        icon = pm.getApplicationIcon(appInfo);

        System.out.println("Icon ==> " +icon);

    }
```

---

How do I return the icons of the currently running tasks and not just the installed applications?

---

Ok, this is what I ended up doing and it appears to be working, but is there a way to retrieve only the tasks that were launched by the user like a task killer would return and not dormant system processes? Can they be filtered by category maybe? The goal is to return a random application icon for one of the currently running tasks that were recently launched by the user, if that helps.

```
int ii=0;

      List< ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> Runningtasks= mgr.getRunningTasks(30);
      for(ii=0;ii<Runningtasks.size();ii++)
      {

         randInt1 = new Random().nextInt(Runningtasks.size());

          ComponentName comName=Runningtasks.get(randInt1).topActivity;
          packageName = comName.getPackageName();
          //String Classname = comName.getClassName();



          System.out.println("icon====> "+icon);
          System.out.println("packageName====> "+packageName);

         // Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(pm, packageName, LONG);
         // toast1.show();
      }


      try{
          icon = pm.getApplicationIcon(packageName);
          }catch(Exception e){}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ActivityManager.getRunningTasks()` to get the list of running [tasks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks(int)). That list would have a [RunningTaskInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo.html) which contains a field names baseActivity that is a ComponentName.

From that you can do something like:

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
ApplicationInfo appInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo(componentName.getPackageName(), 0);
... // rest of the code as you previously did..
```

Comment: Is there a an easy way for me to get the tasks that were  launched by the user kind of like a task killer would show? See my edit above...

Comment: Try to take a look at the ActivityManager docs (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html), there are several methods that might help you. Like getRecentTasks(), getRunningAppProcesses(), ...

Answer (score 1):

```
List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> list = activityManager.getRunningTasks(30); 

    randInt1 = new Random().nextInt(list.size());

    ApplicationInfo appInfo = list.get(randInt1);
    packageName = appInfo.packageName;
    appLabel = (String) pm.getApplicationLabel(appInfo);
    icon = pm.getApplicationIcon(appInfo);

    System.out.println("Icon ==> " +icon);
```

> ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo
>
> Class Overview
>
> Information you can retrieve about a particular task that is currently "running" in the system. Note that a running task does not
>   mean the given task actually has a process it is actively running in;
>   it simply means that the user has gone to it and never closed it, but
>   currently the system may have killed its process and is only holding
>   on to its last state in order to restart it when the user returns.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo.html

After, that will be easy to get the icon!

Comment: Isn't this wrong: ApplicationInfo appInfo = list.get(randInt1); ? The list contains RunningTaskInfo, which is not a subclass of ApplicationInfo...

Comment: Is there a an easy way for me to get the tasks that were  launched by the user kind of like a task killer would show? See my edit above...

Answer (score 0):

```
Drawable icon = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon("com.example.testnotification");
imageView.setImageDrawable(icon);
```